# How to know when the conversion operator is called

Tags: c++

I have been reading about the conversion operator however I am still not sure when the conversion operator is called. Consider the following example:

```
class foo
{
public:
    operator char*()
    {
        return "SomeText";
    }
};


foo d;
const char* m = static_cast<char*>(d);
```

Why is the conversion operator called with this cast ?  Which operator is calling it ?

Comment: Why wouldn't your conversion operator be called? You are explicitly requesting a conversion to `char*` from your object `d`.

Comment: I was under the impression that conversion operator is only called if an operator is placed before an object instance

Comment: Conversion functions aren't "operators", despite the keyword `operator` in their names.

Comment: You don't need to use `static_cast`, just put `d` as an argument of function to a place where `char*` type is expected.

Comment: "I was under the impression that conversion operator is only called if an operator is placed before an object instance" - wrong - you haven't made the conversion `explicit`, so it is implicitly considered whenever the context referring to a `foo` doesn't make sense (can't be compiled) without such a conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing from [static_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) documentation

> If a temporary object of type `new_type` can be declared and initialized
>   with `expression`, as by `new_type Temp(expression);`, which may involve
>   implicit conversions, a call to the constructor of `new_type` or a call
>   to a user-defined conversion operator, then
>   `static_cast<new_type>(expression)` computes and returns the value of that
>   temporary object.

And that's not an operator as T.C. noted, it's a [conversion function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)